# Text color changes in the react script

Tags: javascript

I have one react script.
It works something like this, Data Privacy appears. It is triggered automatically until people opt out.
The color of the drop-down text is blue and I don't understand why. But I want to change the text color to white
Is there a way to add styles to this code and change the text color?

```
<script>
  window.consentManagerConfig = function(exports) {
    var React = exports.React
    var inEU = exports.inEU

    var bannerContent = React.createElement(
      'span',
      null,
      'Wir verwenden Cookies (und andere ähnliche Technologien), um Daten zu sammeln und Ihre Erfahrung auf unserer Website zu verbessern. Durch die Nutzung unserer Website erklären Sie sich mit der Erfassung von Daten, wie in unserer Datenschutzerklärung beschrieben, einverstanden. | We use cookies (and other similar technologies) to collect data to improve your experience on our site. By using our website, you՚re agreeing to the collection of data as described in our',
      ' ',
      React.createElement(
        'a',
        { href: 'https://www.top.legal/de/datenschutz', target: '_blank' },
        'Datenschutzerklärung | Data Privacy Policy'
      ),
      '.'
    )
    var bannerSubContent = 'Sie können Ihre Einstellungen jederzeit ändern. | You can change your preferences at any time.'
    var preferencesDialogTitle = 'Website-Datenerfassungspräferenzen | Website Data Collection Preferences'
    var preferencesDialogContent =
      'Wir verwenden die von Cookies und JavaScript-Bibliotheken gesammelten Daten, um Ihr Browsing-Erlebnis zu verbessern, den Website-Verkehr zu analysieren, personalisierte Werbung auszuliefern und die Gesamtleistung unserer Website zu steigern. | We use data collected by cookies and JavaScript libraries to improve your browsing experience, analyze site traffic, deliver personalized advertisements, and increase the overall performance of our site.'
    var cancelDialogTitle = 'Sind Sie sicher, dass Sie abbrechen möchten? | Are you sure you want to cancel?'
    var cancelDialogContent =
      'Ihre Einstellungen wurden nicht gespeichert. Indem Sie unsere Website weiter nutzen, stimmen Sie unserer Richtlinie zur Datenerfassung auf der Website zu. | Your preferences have not been saved. By continuing to use our website, you՚re agreeing to our Website Data Collection Policy.'
      
    return {
      container: '#opt-in',
      writeKey: 'xH4L6pDELr0qFKjutaGXDqPt9tExOM0n',
      shouldRequireConsent: inEU,
      bannerContent: bannerContent,
      bannerSubContent: bannerSubContent,
      preferencesDialogTitle: preferencesDialogTitle,
      preferencesDialogContent: preferencesDialogContent,
      cancelDialogTitle: cancelDialogTitle,
      cancelDialogContent: cancelDialogContent
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

## Use CSS

It seems like the thing you're calling a "drop-down" is a `<span>` with an `<a>` inside it.

You should use CSS to style these elements.

A `<span>` normally does not try to set its text color, but `<a>` elements do receive some special styling from browsers by default. Those styles are very easily overridden.

First, the outermost element of your "drop-down" should be given a good class name, so these special styles can target it and nothing else. In my example, I will pretend you've assigned the class "gdpr-notice" to the outermost `<span>`.

```css
.gdpr-notice a,
.gdpr-notice a:visited {
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: Great! In that case, you should consider marking this as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the color by easaly adding id or class to your link element. for example:

```
var bannerContent = React.createElement(
      'span',
      null,
      'Wir verwenden Cookies (und andere ähnliche Technologien), um Daten zu sammeln und Ihre Erfahrung auf unserer Website zu verbessern. Durch die Nutzung unserer Website erklären Sie sich mit der Erfassung von Daten, wie in unserer Datenschutzerklärung beschrieben, einverstanden. | We use cookies (and other similar technologies) to collect data to improve your experience on our site. By using our website, you՚re agreeing to the collection of data as described in our',
      ' ',
      React.createElement(
        'a',
        { href: 'https://www.top.legal/de/datenschutz', target: '_blank', id: 'data-privacy-policy' },
        'Datenschutzerklärung | Data Privacy Policy'
      ),
      '.'
    )
```

and then is css

```
#data-privacy-policy { color: white }
```